# Does overriding this method violate LSP?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, liskov-substitution

If a base class `Logger` has a method `reportError` that takes an `Error` object and formats it as a string.

If a subclass implements that method but outputs the string in a different format, yet a string format nonetheless, does it violate the LSP?

I know that adding methods to the subclass doesn’t violate the LSP, it just needs to be able to be tested where it’s base class is used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That depends.

The LSP is about constraints on the methods - their inputs, their outputs, and their calling sequence.

If the requirements on the output of `reportError` are just "returns some string", then you're fine.

If the requirements explicitly state that the string has to be in a certain format, then you're in trouble.

Remember, not all requirements are necessarily expressible in the typesystem.

Comment: So if the requirement were that latter one, would it be better to add another method that produces the new format rather than attempting to override the base implementation?

Comment: @datta, Perhaps it would be good to add as a new method. Though without changing the consuming clients, no on will call your new method.  You might also consider changing the definition of the original method (and fix any issues with that, as software is *soft*).

Comment: @ErikEidt Unfortunately I have no control over the base class. The result from the method in question goes to file for later reading (review of the log). The only dependency would be if somebody was parsing log files. I need to add additional behavior to the base class, but I wanted to change how one of its implementations functioned (as in, altering the final format). Current consumers of the base class method will just see a new output format, does that cause an LSP violation? The program is not dependent on the output of the method.

Comment: @datta - in other words, if you have a lot of other code that *relies* on that string being in a certain format, then adding an override that violates that expectation gets you in trouble. If you don't have a lot of code that's like that, you can introduce a change on the expectations set by the base class (and require future clients that want to use it polymorphically not to expect a specific string format), or you can choose to leave it as is, and introduce a new method.

Comment: "The only dependency would be if somebody was parsing log files" - if there's nothing doing that at the moment, then I would say you're OK.

Comment: Still, something worth documenting. Requirements like to change.

Comment: @datta: Why does it matter if this falls under the term "LSP violation"? The only thing which matters is, will the change break existing code. The people whose code will break will not be very pleased when you tell them *"hey, I asked some strangers from the internet, and they told me it is not an LSP violation, since the requirements for the output format are not clearly documented, so I am fine"*.

Comment: @DocBrown I was looking at how to change how a base class function behaved. What I stumbled upon was the LSP and was unfamiliar with it. This change does not break existing code, since all logging in the program is just output to file. To me, I thought the LSP extends beyond my program where the instances exist; by that, if my program outputs a file in a specific format, and another's program uses that format, does the change in method behavior (new format) violate the LSP? So when you say "those people whose code will break", I have to account for their programs too?

Comment: @datta: your question already got a correct answer, so I won't write another one. But let me add a note: requirements for checking the LSP can be defined more strictly by introducing (and coding!) preconditions, postconditions and invariants see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). Unit tests are also useful for this (which can be seen as representative examples for the requirements). But if you have no formalized (pre/post)conditions, no unit tests and not even an informally documented contract for the Logger, then it is impossible to decide if there ...

Comment: ... an LSP violation, or not. So what remains is to look at the existing software which uses the Logger's output and analyse which requirements it has. If there is none, it is more a matter of perspective if you prefer to say "there is no LSP violation" or "we can currently not decide about the LSP".

Comment: @DocBrown So when looking at it objectively, I do have to consider external programs that use the final output. While the change may not break my program, it could cause a problem for someone else's. If that's the case, can one not simply document the change in output and broadcast that to users of said output? Surely program versioning allows for this.

Comment: @datta: if that's feasible this depends heavily on who and how many people are using the logging software or its output. In your situation, it may be easy. But to get a notion where this might not be that simple any more, I recommend you have a look into ["Martian Headsets" by Joel Spolsky](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2008/03/17/martian-headsets/), one of the founders of Stackoverflow, btw.